# How to set the title on Chart through Code in C#

Tags: c#

How do I set the Title of a chart in Windows form in c#? I don't want to set it in the designer properties. I want it to set when a button is clicked. for example:

```
public void button2_click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
  chart1.Title.Text = "Sales";

}
```

Comment: is that work for you ??

Comment: its good to accept answer that is helpful to you and upvote it ...

Comment: yes it is working thank you very much! & sorry i don't even know how to accept answers on here ..kinda new

Comment: Dont forget to mark it as accepted as its worked for you...thanks

Comment: yeah .. I rated it up .. does that mean I've marked it a answered ?

Comment: if it work for you than you can mark it as accepted else it ok...you can accept answer by clicking on right sign below voting meter

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try this

```
   // Set title.
this.chart1.Titles.Add("Sales");
```

Answer (score 2):

try this..

```
this.chart1.Titles.Add("Sales");
```

you can get this title by using

```
System.Windows.Forms.DataVisualization.Charting.Title title1 = this.chart1.Titles(0);
```